# Browser sync with gulp and Ghost blog

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, browser-sync

I'm running a Ghost blog which is simply started with:
`npm start`

It then runs on `http://lolcahost:2368`

I have browser sync setup to run in my gulpfile like so:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {

  browserSync.init(null, {
    server: {
      proxy: 'http://localhost:2368'
    }
  });

});
```

Doesn't seen to work though. It launches in my browser on `localhost:3000` but just displays a message on a completely blank white page: `Cannot GET /`

What am I doing wrong here? I can see the site fine when I visit the `localhost:2368` that Ghost creates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your are passing the configs wrong,

It should be something like this:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {

  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://localhost:2368'
  });

});
```

Comment: So simple! Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @Coop you confused the server option with the proxy. Broswersync can either serve your files for you or proxy all the requests to your server.